# Vba code for keeping chart object on one sheet when using range.exporttopdf method

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that outputs a range and a pivotchart to pdf. At this point I am struggling to have the chart element on one page instead of it possibly being cutoff. Here is my code:

```
With nxraySheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 85
        .LeftMargin = 0
        .RightMargin = 0
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        End With

        nxraySheet.Columns("A:H").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        nxraySheet.Range("A:H").ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="Blah Blah Blah\Test Location\AVITEST\PDFs\X-Rays\" & "X-Ray-" & facilityList.Cells(i, 1) & "-" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsx", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

[[image: PDF]]

Comment: Does the chart print to 1 page normally without VBA ?

Comment: Seems to me that you have not set up Print Area correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, unfortunately you can not tell a chart to be printed as a whole (would be like "Excel, please move the chart some rows up or down to get printed altogether").

Here are some options:

**Overall Zoom**

You can not have both `FitToPagesWide = 1` and `Zoom = 85` at the same time. This doesn't raise an error, but these settings conflict with each other and zoom factor wins.
So you may decide for a lower zoom factor:

```
With nxraySheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = 75
```

**Fit vertically on 1 Page**

If you want it to fit vertically on 1 page, reset the zoom factor first:

```
With nxraySheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = False
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
```

**Fit horizontally on 1 Page, add Page Break**

You can print with 1 page width and add a manual horizontal page break directly before the PivotChart:

```
With nxraySheet
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
    .ResetAllPageBreaks
    .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.ChartObjects(1).TopLeftCell.Row
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I didn't know about the HPageBreaks.add property.

Comment: Fine :) Then please mark my answer as "accepted answer" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Ha, sorry there you go. Thanks again!